# How to disable JSP Compilation during runtime in tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, compilation, pre-compilation

I need to disable jsp compilation during runtime. I already have pre-compiled all the jsp files into the product. In production environment I do not want any new jsp to run.

Answer (score 0):

By default a JSP will only be complied once until you changes it. You have nothing to do for achieving that. For your confirmation you can call a JSP first time and you will observe that it took much time than when you will call the same (unmodified) JSP second time.

Comment: My requirement is, I should not allow running new jsp in my production environment other than pre-compiled JSPs. So I need to disable compiling JSPs in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jasper2 production configuration to disable the JSP compilation at runtime.

Refer : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Production_Configuration

Setting development=false will solve your problem.